# How to get the value from css of "div" tag using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ex:

```
<div id="h" style="background-image:url('images//line.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat-x; width:300px; height:25px; padding-left:10px; color:white;">Frame</div>
```

Now, I want to get the value of width from style using jQuery. What should be jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#h').width()   //  from jQuery dimensions (core)
```

or

```
$('#h').css('width');
```

`.width()` returns the **calculated** width. `.css('width')` just returns whatever you've written into the style. So in general, it's a better idea to stick with `.width()` unless you really want to know the actuall value.

If you need the width of an element in more "detail", check out the `.innerWidth()` and `.outerWidth()` methods from jQuery dimensions. Those calculate the width with `padding`, `borders`, `padding` etc.

Ref.: [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/), [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/), [.innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$("#h").css("width");
```

Using the css method and the property name of width will give you the actual css result, as apposed to `width()` which will give a unitless result.

From the [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) docs:

> The difference between .css(width) and
>   .width() is that the latter returns a
>   unit-less pixel value (for example,
>   400) while the former returns a value
>   with units intact (for example, 400px).

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
$('#h').width();
```

or

```
$('#h').css('width');
```

The latter returns the unit value (eg 300px), the former just a value (300).

See [jQuery Width() API](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 0):

The [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
var width = $('#h').css('width');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery like this:

```
alert($("#h").css("width"));
```

To play a little with jQuery you should use...

**http://jsfiddle.net/WEWVp/**